# Streamlining OpenAPI Error Response Documentation in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I am working on a Spring Boot project where we extensively use OpenAPI for documenting our REST APIs. We have a wide range of custom error codes, and currently, we document these using @ApiResponse annotations for each possible error code at individual endpoints. This approach, however, leads to cluttered and verbose controller methods, especially when numerous error responses are involved.

Here's an example of our current implementation:

```
@GetMapping("/someEndpoint")
@Operation(summary = "Get some data")
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Successful retrieval"),
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Bad Request", content = @Content),
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Unauthorized", content = @Content)
})
public ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> getSomeData() {
    // Endpoint logic
}
```

I'm aware of the possibility of creating custom annotations to manage the documentation of various error responses in our Spring Boot application. The problem is that separate the problem elsewhere, and I'm not in favour of that either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.